# Which are blocking Vulkan functions?

Tags: multithreading, vulkan

In Vulkan, it is recommended to break the API calls into separate threads for better throughput. I am unsure which category of calls are the computationally expensive one which would cause the thread to block, and thus should be used asynchronously.

As I see it, these are the potential calls/family-of-calls that could take a long time to execute.

- vkAcquireImageKHR()
- vkQueueSubmit()
- vkQueuePresentKHR()
- memcpy into mapped memory
- vkBegin/EndCommandBuffer
- vkCmd* calls for drawing and compute

But, the more I think about them, the more it seems that most would be fairly cheap to call. I'll explain my rational, which is probably flawed.

**vkAcquireImageKHR()**

This could block, if you choose a timeout. But, it's likely that a sufficiently optimized app would call this function with a 0 timeout, and just do other work if the image is not yet available. So, this function can be made instant. There's no need to wait, if the app is smart enough.

**vkQueueSubmit()**

This function takes a fence, which will be signaled when the GPU has finished executing the command buffers. So, it doesn't actually wait around while the GPU performs the work. I'm assuming this function is the one that starts the physical movement of the command buffer data to the GPU, but I'm assuming that it tell the hardware to read from some memory location, and then the function returns as quickly as possible. So, it wouldn't wait around while the command buffers get sent to the GPU.

**vkQueuePresentKHR()**

Signal to the GPU to send some image to the window/monitor. It doesn't have to wait for much, does it?

**memcpy into mapped memory**

This is probably slow.

**vkCmd* calls**

This family of calls is the one I'm most unsure about. When I read about threads and Vulkan, it's usually these calls that get put onto the threads. But, what are these calls doing, really? Are they building some opcode buffer, made up of some ints and pointers, to be sent to the GPU? If so, that should be extremely fast. The actual work would be carrying out the operations described by those opcodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define "block". The [traditional definition of "block"ing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)) is to wait on some internal synchronization, and thereby taking longer than would strictly be necessary for the operation. Doing a `memcpy` is not doing any synchronization; it's just copying data.

So you don't seem to be concerned about "block"ing; you're merely talking about what operations are *expensive*.

`vkQueueSubmit` does not block. But that doesn't mean it's not *expensive*. It is not "tell[ing] the hardware to read from some memory location" Just look at its interface. It doesn't take a single command buffer; it takes an *arbitrary number of them*, which are grouped into batches, with each batch waiting on semaphores before execution, signaling semaphores after execution, and the whole operation signaling a fence.

You cannot reasonably expect an implementation of such a thing to merely copy some pointers around.

And that doesn't even get into issues of different types of command buffers. Submitting `SIMULTANEOUS_USE` command buffers may require creating temporary copies of its buffered data, so that different batches can contain the same command buffer.

Now obviously, `vkQueueSubmit` is going to return well before any of the work it submits actually gets executed. But don't make the mistake of thinking that it's free to ship work off to the GPU. The Vulkan specification takes time out in a note to directly tell you not to call the function any more frequently than you can get away with:

> Submission can be a high overhead operation, and applications **should** attempt to batch work together into as few calls to `vkQueueSubmit` as possible.

The reason to present on the same thread that submitted the CBs that generates the image being presented is not because any of those operations are necessarily slow. It's for simple pragmatism; these three operations (acquire, submit, present) must happen *in order*. And the simplest and easiest way to ensure that is to do them on the same thread.

You cannot submit work that renders to a swapchain image until you have acquired it. Therefore, either you do it on the same thread, or you have to have some inter-thread communication pipe to tell the thread waiting to build the primary CB what the acquired image is. The two processes *cannot* overlap.

Unlike acquire, present is a queue operation. And both `vkQueueSubmit` and `vkQueuePresent` require that access to their `VkQueue` parameters must be "externally synchoronized". That of course means that you cannot call them both from different threads, on the same `VkQueue`, at the same time. So if you tried to do these in parallel, you'd need a mutex or something to synchronize CPU access to the `VkQueue`.

Whereas if you do them on the same thread, there's no need.

Additionally, in order to present an image, you must provide a semaphore that the present will wait on. This semaphore will get signaled by the batch that generates data for the image. Vulkan requires semaphore signal/wait pairs to be *ordered*; you cannot perform a queue operation that waits on a semaphore until the operation that signals that semaphore has been submitted. Therefore, either you do it on the same thread in sequence, or you use some inter-thread communication pipe to tell whatever thread is waiting to present the image that the submit operation that renders to it has been issued.

So what is to be gained by splitting these operations up onto different threads? They *have to* happen in sequence, so you may as well do them in sequence the easiest way that exists: on the same thread.

While timeline semaphores now allow you to call the present function before submitting the work that increments the semaphore counter, you still can't call them on separate threads (without synchronization) because they affect the same queue. So you may as well issue them on the same thread (though not necessarily in acquire, submit, present order).

Ultimately, it's not clear what the point of this exercise is. Yes, an individual `vkCmd*` call will be pretty fast. So what? In a real scene, you will be calling these functions *thousands* of times per frame. Spreading them evenly across 4 cores saves you ~4x the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That answers my questions. About the "Ultimately, it's not clear what the point of this exercise is.". I don't see how you can't see how valuable this information is to an amateur. At the beginning, when learning something like Vulkan (specially without graphics programming experience), a person will live in constant speculation. I articulated the reasoning for my thinking, and that I feel that my mind is leading me to an incorrect assumption. The point is to get clarity, precisely to avoid speculating.